# Smooth structures on noncompact 6-manifolds

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology

Does a noncompact, simply connected 6-manifold have a unique smooth structure? Maybe with more assumptions like having torsion-free homology and being spin?

Note that in the compact case C.T.C. Wall showed that this is true. Can counterexamples be constructed with exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$s, e.g. $X\times S^2$ with $X$ an exotic $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Any related references would be appreciated.

Comment: For compact part Wall proved that if torsion vanish then it is true

Comment: He also assumed the manifold is spin, as I stated above.

Comment: Yeah and $w_2=0$.

Comment: @AnubhavMukherjee That is what spin means.

Comment: @MikeMiller In my first comment I forgot to mention $w_2$...and I know that it is the meaning of spin :P

Comment: OP: For what it's worth, the Hirsch-Mazur classification of smooth structures on a PL manifold works for noncompact manifolds, and in particular shows that if $M$ is a PL manifold of dimension at most $6$ (or a noncompact manifold of dimension at most $7$), $M$ has a unique compatible PL structure up to concordance; if $\dim M \geq 5$ then concordance implies PL homeomorphism. So you are reduced to whether or not your topological manifold admits a unique PL structure. This is governed by a comparatively simpler obstruction theory; chase the references in Milnor, "diff top 46 yrs later".

Comment: @MikeMiller Do you know example of any open exotic 6 manifold (ignore simplyconnected)?